# How to get Canon Pixma MG3660 to scan?

Tags: printing, scanner, canon

I have searched through all the advice and followed all the steps.
But I can't get the printer to work without problems.
But the scanner has proved impossible to get to work.
After many hours of trying, I have decided that the best thing to do is use a skip bin and find an all-in-one that will actually be an all-in-one.

Could you please advise as to which brand and model.
Canon was just a complete waste of money and their support a joke.

Comment: IIRC, canon offers an application called scangear mp that can be used to scan. However, my experience with canon printers is similar and I wouldn't recommend them for use with Linux. My HP OfficeJet works quite well with Linux, but I won't recommend any products here...

Comment: Have you tried the official Linux drivers and scanner software for your printer? You can download them from here: https://www.canon.com.au/printers/pixma-mg3660/support  Our Canon MB model works quite well, the only limitation is that I have to use the official Canon scanning software to get the document feeder to work.

Comment: thank you for the reply. the problem was solved with the use of skip bin and I am looking into something more compatible possibly epsom.Possibly ubuntu may one day come up with a "Ubuntu friendly "certification or grading so mugs like me don,t waste money supporting the profits of those to arrogant to supply user friendly installation for linux etc